# php selection is not working

Tags: php, mysql

In select it dynamically shows value which is fetched from database,what i wanted to do is user select the value from dropdown list i.e-the values that are actually in the database and when users submit the delete,mysql deletes that selected user.why it is not working ?

```
<?php

    // Database Constants
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_NAME", "audit");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "123456");

    // Create a database connection
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select a database to use 
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Delete Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    $username = $_POST['react'];

    if(!empty($username])) {
        $query= "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            print("<strong>$user</strong>Successfully Deleted<p>");
        }
        else {
            print("<strong>no users are available to delete yet, sorry. </strong><p>");
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="Delete_user.php"><div align="center"><center>                                              <p>Delete users
    <input type="hidden" name="react" value="delete_user
           <select name="user" size="1">
    <?php 
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY username";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$connection);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
            //we have atleast one user,so show all users as options in select
            while ($rows = mysq_fetch_row($result))
            {
                print("<option value=\"$rows[0]\">$rows[0]</option>");
            }
        }
        else {
            print("<option value=\"\">Please Select User</option>");
        }
    ?>
    </select><input type="submit" value="submit"></center></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `not working` Also, do not use `mysql*` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Please try to show an error message that you get that indicates it's not working

Comment: what do you get if you `print_r($rows);`

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid. `<center>` is deprecated and if you do use it, close the `<p>` before you close the `<center>`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a substitute for your error log, which you should be reading

Answer (score 1):

Check your **second `if()` statement.**

```
if(!empty($username])) { ...
```

There's a square bracket there.

Next, in your form near the bottom, you have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="react" value="delete_user
```

This should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="react" value="delete_user" />
```

Everything else looks okay. Try to pay attention to your error messages.

Comment: Also he is getting a value from `$_POST` without knowing whether the key exists. `$username = isset($_POST['react']) ? $_POST['react'] : NULL;`

Comment: ok now there is no mysql error but there is no options in the dropdown,there is a dropdown option but its blank,thoughin my table users there is four user already created my users table structure is following :
TABLE users- 
id,
username,
password.

Comment: I just looked again, and it seems you misspelled a function. `mysq_fetch_row($result)` is missing an "L" and should be `mysql_fetch_row($result)`.

Comment: ok now this page is ok when i select user and submit it the following error come
"Warning:mysql_num_rows()expects parameter 1 to be resource,boolean given in C:\www\login\delete.php on line 15"

Comment: That means one of your SQL queries returned `false` (meaning it failed), and that value of `false` is being sent to one of your `mysql_num_rows` functions. Take a look at your query indicated on line 15, and check the contents of `mysql_error()`.

Comment: i am not understanding what to do now,what code should i change ?

Answer (score 0):

Error in this line

```
while ($rows = mysq_fetch_row($result))
```

change to

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_row($result))
```

Comment: "Warning:mysql_num_rows()expects parameter 1 to be resource,boolean given in C:\www\login\delete.php on line 15"